# No estoy pudiendo cargar una fecha anterior a 1800

Tags: genexus

Estoy intentando cargar una fecha anterior a 1800 y me retorna una error. Las propiedades de validación están por defecto. ¿Hay algo que tenga que configurar para que acepte estas fechas?

gracias,

[image: Problema al intentar cargar una fecha anterior a 1800]

Comment: puedes colocar algo del codigo que usas y comentarnos mas sobre el entorno del mismo (libreria usada, desktop, mobile, web, etc)

Comment: Hola @EmanuelFriedrich, es Genexus 16 U8 con WorkWithPlus, CSharp/WEB. Agrego imagenes con las propiedades del atributo.

Answer (score 0):

Estas son las propiedades del atributo.
[image: Propiedades 1/2]

[image: Propiedades 2/2]

Comment: Esto hace parte de la pregunta??